# How to create database-like relations between Python objects

Tags: python, relationship

Say I have a type of object `Foo` and another called `Bar`. Say `Foo`s can "have" 0 or more `Bar`s, and that all `Bar`s must have a single `Foo`. Something like this doesn't feel right because there's no straight-forward way of enforcing consistency:

```py
@dataclass
class Foo:
    some_field: object
    bars: Optional[list[Bar]] = None


@dataclass
class Bar:
    a_field: object
    foo: Foo
```

To be clear, by "enforcing consistency" what I mean is that if a `Foo` claims to have a list of `Bar`s then those `Bar`s should all claim to have that `Foo`.

I could instead use mappings. But now I need to create IDs which maybe I don't need for any other purpose, and consistency is still not straight-forward to enforce.

```py
@dataclass
class Foo:
    some_field: object

@dataclass
class Bar:
    a_field: object

id_to_foo = {0: a_foo, 1: another_foo, ...}
id_to_bar = {0: a_bar, 1: another_bar, ...}
foo_to_bar = {0: [0, 1], 1: [1, 2, 3], ...}
```

I could make the relation explicit one way, and implicit the other way like so:

```py
@dataclass
class Foo:
    some_field: object
    bars: Optional[list[Bar]] = None

@dataclass
class Bar:
    a_field: object
```

This would partially solve consistency (although I still am not enforcing that each `Bar` has exactly one `Foo`). But then every time I want to know which `Foo` a `Bar` belongs to, I'd need to round up all my `Foo`s and run through their lists checking for an `id` match.

What's the simplest way to achieve this many-to-one relation in Python, without writing a bunch of boiler-plate machinery myself?

Comment: Just a little context for those answering. I've been working with Python for *years* and I'm quite advanced with it. I just never did formal CS studies so every now and then something seemingly super basic like this just bamboozles me completely and it feels crazy that I don't know how to deal with it. So yeah, feel free to assume I know Python but I just have random holes in my knowledge on data-structures and the like.

Comment: For the vote to close because it's opinion based, actually that's useful information. If someone answers this with "there's no clear cut answer, python isn't designed to do this. that's actually a good answer". I'm not looking for opinions.

Comment: This isn't really an appropriate question here, it's too open ended.   That said, maybe check out pydantic.  Doing this kind of data validation per regular doesn't really feel like the Python way to me, however....

Comment: @BadZen it doesn't feel Pythonic, but... I'm working on the biggest code base I ever have, and for some reason, everything I do keeps pointing me towards this sort of relation-constraining approach. Will check out Pydantic. Thanks.

Comment: `bars: Optional[list[Foo]] = None` should probably be `bars: list[Foo] = field(default_factory=list)`. Type checking with mypy would help avoiding code that  mistakenly adds a `Baz` to the `bars` list. Or look at `pydantic` as @BadZen suggested since it provides tools for validating the data you are instantiating from. I don't really understand why you need to invent some ids, I think maybe you have created a problem to solve by analogy that doesn't exist in practice.

Comment: @Anentropic I definitely feel like I'm creating a problem that doesn't exist. (side note: I edited bars because I needed a `list[Bar]` not a `list[Foo]`). I get your point about using a default factory, but that's less what I'm concerned about. I'm not even sure `pydantic` is the right thing. The "consistency" I'm trying to achieve is that if a Foo claims to have a bunch of Bars then those Bars should all say that they have that Foo. Python doesn't offer a way to atomically set these relationships, which means I basically have to write the machinery to do so.

Comment: ah that is a much clearer description of the problem you want to solve, I suggest adding that to the question

Comment: Can you detail a bit more the interaction between FOO and BAR? i.e. will you add BAR to FOO, FOO to BAR or both?

Comment: @RomainL. conceptually I announce a relation: "This foo belongs to this bar". It's really as simple as that. How I do that is my question. And it needs to be in a way that makes sure all foos have at least one bar, and all bars are owned by exactly one foo. So then to answer your question: it's both.